# How to unpack/convert binary data in a file into readable values?

Tags: python, binary, binary-data

I have a .pcd file and when I open it with i text editor, i see this:

```
# .PCD v0.7 - Point Cloud Data file format
VERSION 0.7
FIELDS x y z _
SIZE 4 4 4 1
TYPE F F F U
COUNT 1 1 1 4
WIDTH 246564
HEIGHT 1
VIEWPOINT 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
POINTS 246564
DATA binary
É,>  Ì= €¿  €?  .>  Ì=ÃY¿  €?  .>Ì~Í= €¿  €?  2>  Ì=5a¿  €?  2>øuÍ= €¿  
€?  6>  Ì=Ûv¿  €?  6>²vÌ= €¿  €?¹“6>  Ì= €¿  €?CÊ">  Ä= €¿  €?  &  Ä=…¿
......
```

The document of this format is here: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/pcd_file_format.php

Example from the documents:

```
# .PCD v.7 - Point Cloud Data file format
VERSION .7
FIELDS x y z rgb
SIZE 4 4 4 4
TYPE F F F F
COUNT 1 1 1 1
WIDTH 213
HEIGHT 1
VIEWPOINT 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
POINTS 213
DATA ascii
0.93773 0.33763 0 4.2108e+06
0.90805 0.35641 0 4.2108e+06
0.81915 0.32 0 4.2108e+06
```

Now I want to convert these binary datas into numbers like in the documents. As I see I can use python struck.unpack but I couldn't figure out how to do that.

Comment: `struct.unpack('f', 'É,>'.encode())` converts `'É,>'` to `float` 0.16849426925182343

Comment: using Google `"python PCD"` I found [PyPCD](https://github.com/dimatura/pypcd) which probably may resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `struct` and the provided file is the only one you want to extract the data from, this is one way you could do it:

```py
import struct

with open("your_file.pcd") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

unpacker = struct.Struct("fff4B")
packed_data = lines[-1]
x = []
y = []
z = []
_ = []
for i in range(0, 246564):
    try:
        unpacked = unpacker.unpack_from(packed_data[i:])
    except struct.error:
        break
    x.append(unpacked[0])
    y.append(unpacked[1])
    z.append(unpacked[2])
    _.append(unpacked[3:])

print(x)
print(y)
print(z)
print(_)
```

This is certainly not a general approach to parse PCD files like [PyPCD](https://github.com/dimatura/pypcd) is, but it does work for this specific file and dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the tool `pcl_convert_pcd_ascii_binary`.

*e.g.*

```bash
pcl_convert_pcd_ascii_binary input_binary_file.pcd output_ascii_file.pcd 0
```

The number `0` in the command means to convert ascii format.
And then you can get the file `output_ascii_file.pcd` that you can figure out the number.[Reference link1](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/pcl_convert_pcd_ascii_binary.1.html) and [Reference link2](https://github.com/PointCloudLibrary/pcl/blob/master/io/tools/convert_pcd_ascii_binary.cpp)